# Upload Files To Dropbox In ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox

I'm having a problem finding what I need and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Here's my scenario:

There are two users, one creates the form, the other fills the form out.

User A creates a form with a file upload.
User B fills out said form and uploads appropriate file(s) to server.
Said file is asynchronously uploaded to User A's Dropbox account.

Keep in mind that User A has already given the necessary authentication in a different module.

I'm OK with using a third-party library if need be as it doesn't appear that Dropbox has an API for ASP.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this: https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet Looks like it is maintained.